# Error in web worker using web assembly

Tags: javascript, c, emscripten, webassembly

I would like to use WebAssembly within a web worker.

From my main application, I launch it like this:

```
let w = new Worker('test.js');
w.onmessage = (event) => { console.log(event); };
w.onerror = (event) => { console.error(event); };
w.postMessage({ message: "Hello World" });
```

Then, I created a file `test.js` as follows:

```
self.Module = {
    locateFile: function (s) {
        console.log(s);
        return s;
    }
};

self.importScripts("main.js"); 
// note: `main.js` is the JavaScript glue file created by emcc

self.onmessage = function(messageEvent) {
    console.log(messageEvent); // works!
    console.log(self.Module); // works!
    console.log(self.Module.ccall("test")); // crashes!
}
```

I get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined`. I don't understand why `self.Module` is undefined, how is that possible?

I have the feeling there is something about the scope of the web worker and WebAssembly that does not work well together.

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that console.log() does not reveal the true state of the object at execution time. Further digging revealed that in fact the object `Module` was not ready yet.

I cite from: https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/FAQ.html

> **How can I tell when the page is fully loaded and it is safe to call compiled functions?**
>
> Calling a compiled function before a page has fully loaded can result
>   in an error, if the function relies on files that may not be present
>
> [...]
>
> Another option is to define an
>   onRuntimeInitialized function: 
>   `Module['onRuntimeInitialized'] = function() { ... };`
>
> That method will be called when the runtime is ready and it is ok for you to call compiled code.

Adjusting my `test.js` (worker) file fixes the issue:

```
self.Module = {
    locateFile: function (s) {
        console.log(s);
        return s;
    }
    // Add this function
    onRuntimeInitialized: function() {
        test();
    }
};

self.importScripts("main.js"); 
// note: `main.js` is the JavaScript glue file created by emcc

self.data = {};

// to pass data from the main JS file
self.onmessage = function(messageEvent) {
    console.log(messageEvent); // works!
    self.data = messageEvent; // save the data
}

// gets executed when everything is ready.
self.test = function() {
    // we may safely use self.data and self.Module now!
    console.log(self.Module.ccall("test")); // works!
}
```